# How to add long text to BAL messages?

Tags: logging, abap

I create a log like this:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_LOG_CREATE'
      EXPORTING
        i_s_log      = ls_log
      IMPORTING
        e_log_handle = mv_log_handle.
```

Then I add a msg to it like this:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_LOG_MSG_ADD'
        EXPORTING
          i_log_handle     = mv_log_handle
          i_s_msg          = ls_msg
        IMPORTING
          e_msg_was_logged = lv_was_logged.
```

After I save it, I go to transaction `slg1` search my log object and find my msg:
[image: Log Msg in SLG1]
But in a SAP demo program SBAL_DEMO_02 I see a log msg like this:
[image: Log Msg with Ltxt]
It has a cool question mark button on the right, if I click it I can see even more text.

I want it in my log too, **how do I add this to my log message?**

I went through the code of SBAL_DEMO_02 but I still don't get how they added it.

Comment: Well... maybe that's because your message is defined in SE91 as self explanatory?

Comment: @Jagger that was it, I didn't have time to post my own answer about that here yet! If you post an answer how to add a longtext to the msg in SE91 after unmarking it as self explanatory I gladly mark it as the answer too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you uncheck the "self-explanatory" flag for your message number then you will get the question mark button for free.

[image: Self explanatory and long text]

Then click the "Long text" button and define your long text.

[image: Defining long text]

Having defined it don't forget to activate it!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right inside the program you mention.  See subroutine

`msg_add_with_extended_longtext`

inside of SBAL_DEMO_02